# Pig Latin getting (ranslatetay) instead of (anslatetray)

Tags: java

How do I make the method indexOfVowel to return 1 for strings such as translate? I need it to find all the consonant that is before a vowel to be moved to the end. If I changed "notVowel" to 2 the word "translate" should be "anslatetray" but it returns ranslatetay. It only checks the first letter but not the rest of the word.

```
    private String translateWord(String word) {
    String translated = "";
    int vowel = 0;
    int notVowel = 1;

    if (vowel == indexOfVowel(word)) {
        return (word + "way ");
    }
    if (notVowel == indexOfVowel(word)) {
        return (word.substring(1) + word.substring(vowel, 1) + "ay ");
    }
    return translated;
}
private static int indexOfVowel(String word) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (isVowel(word.charAt(i))) {
            return i;
        }
        } 
        return word.length();
      
        }
private static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want `indexOfVowel` to return 1 specifically under any case.  You want it to do what it sounds like it will do...return the index of the first vowel in the word passed to it.  If the first vowel happens to be at the beginning of the word, it will return 0, otherwise it will return a non-0 value indicating the location of the first vowel.  You need that location to do the right thing elsewhere.  So `indexOfVowel` is correct as you have it.

Your problem is your use of the `substring` method...understanding how to use it to pick out the right portions of the target word.

Here's a modified version of your code that does the right thing, with comments to explain the two uses of `substring`:

```
public class Test {

    private static String translateWord(String word) {
        int i = indexOfVowel(word);
        if (i == 0) { // if word starts with vowel
            return (word + "way ");
        }
        else { // word doesn't start with a vowel
            // 'i' is the position of the first vowel
            // word.substring(i) = from position of first vowel to end of word
            // word.substring(0, i) = from start of word to char before first vowel
            return (word.substring(i) + word.substring(0, i) + "ay ");
        }
    }

    private static int indexOfVowel(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (isVowel(word.charAt(i))) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return word.length();

    }
    private static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
        switch (ch) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(translateWord("action"));
        System.out.println(translateWord("translate"));
        System.out.println(translateWord("parachute"));
        System.out.println(translateWord("scrap"));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
actionway 
anslatetray 
arachutepay 
apscray
```